# Add new button to tooltip area

Tags: intro.js

I need to add new button or checkbox in order to disable the tour in general for my app. Is it possible add new button into tooltip and catch click on it in order to disable the door forever?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score -1):

```
introJs().setOptions({
   steps: [
       {
         element: '#step1',
         intro: "<button>click me</button>"
       },
   ]
})
```

check this out [html in tooltip](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/html-tooltip/index.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)